# A better way for using DB connection [PDO] using an class and further using it in other class?

Tags: database, class, pdo, database-connection

I'm searching for a better PDO db connection which I could use in the different classes I have. For example my current code is like this:

core.php

```
//Connecting to Database
        try {
        $db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydb", "project", "project123");
        } 
        catch(PDOException $e) {  
        echo $e->getMessage();  
        }
```

class Core {

```
protected $db;
    public function __construct(PDO $db) {
    $this->db = $db;
    }

function redirectTo($page,$mode = 'response',$message = '') {
        if($message != '') {
        header('Location: '.SITEURL.'/'.$page.'?'.$mode.'='.urlencode($message));
        } else {
        header('Location: '.SITEURL.'/'.$page);         
        }
        exit();
}
```

}

And apart from this I have 2 more class: wall.php and ticker.php

```
class Wall {

protected $db;
    public function __construct(PDO $db) {
    $this->db = $db;
    }
function addComment($uid, $fid, $comment) {
$time = time();
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$query = $this->db->prepare('INSERT INTO wall_comments (comment, uid_fk, msg_id_fk, ip, created) VALUES (:comment, :uid, :fid, :ip, :time)');
$query->execute(array(':comment' => $comment, ':uid' => $uid, ':fid' => $fid, ':ip' => $ip, ':time' => $time));

$nofity_msg = "User commented on the post";
$setTicker = Ticker::addTicker($uid,$nofity_msg,'comment');                 

    if($setTicker) {
    Core::redirectTo('wall/view-'.$fid.'/','error','Oops, You have already posted it!');        
    } else {
    Core::redirectTo('wall/view-'.$fid.'/','error','Oops, Error Occured');  
    }
}
```

}

and ticker.php is:

```
class Ticker {  
    protected $db;
    public function __construct(PDO $db) {
    $this->db = $db;
    }


function addTicker($uid,$msg,$type) {
        $time = time();

        $query = $this->db->prepare('INSERT INTO tickers (uid_fk, message, type, created) VALUES (:uid, :message, :type, :time)');

        try {
                $query->execute(array(':uid' => $uid, ':message' => $msg, ':type' => $type, ':time' => $time));
                return $this->db->lastInsertId();
        }
        catch(PDOException $e) {  
                return 0;
        }  

}
```

}

Now my problem is that I need to call for the function addComment() and inside that function there  is a further call for the function addTicker() present in the class Ticker. This is causing a Db connection problem as there is already an db instance created in the previous class or so.. I can't figure out how to sort this out.

This is the code I'm using in the main index file:

```
$core = new Core($db);
$ticker = new Ticker($db);
$wall = new Wall($db);

$wall->addComment($uid, $fid, $add_comment); // This statement is not working.. :(
```

My intention is to have a common main DB connection and further use that connection in other classes. Is there any better way to do it..?

Answer (score 0):

> there is already an db instance created in the previous class

this is actually single instance, but copied into 2 variables.

> This is causing a Db connection problem

Can you please be a bit more certain about such a problem? What particular problem you have?

Comment: Sorry, I had forgotten to add the code I'm using in my index file in the above question. (Edited it now..)

@Your Common Sense
Well, the current error I'm having is that I can't get the statement

$wall->addComment($uid, $fid, $add_comment);

to execute, its encountering error when reaching the line or statement:

$setTicker = Ticker::addTicker($uid,$nofity_msg,'comment');